# Arduino Uno not recognized, /dev/ttyACM0 doesn't exist

Tags: arduino

I recently purchased an arduino uno from sparkfun, and attempted it with a fresh ubuntu 12.04 build. I installed the ide, and it seemed to work fine; I could write the sketches. However, when I plugged the arduino in, it appeared not to recognise it.

I should also note that the arduino does draw power from the USB port, as the green "On" light is illuminated.

The serial port arduino uno should be "assigned to" is /dev/ttyACM0. However, this did not exist, as upon running  `ls dev/tty*`, I got the following results:

```
/dev/tty    /dev/tty23  /dev/tty39  /dev/tty54      /dev/ttyS10  /dev/ttyS26
/dev/tty0   /dev/tty24  /dev/tty4   /dev/tty55      /dev/ttyS11  /dev/ttyS27
/dev/tty1   /dev/tty25  /dev/tty40  /dev/tty56      /dev/ttyS12  /dev/ttyS28
/dev/tty10  /dev/tty26  /dev/tty41  /dev/tty57      /dev/ttyS13  /dev/ttyS29
/dev/tty11  /dev/tty27  /dev/tty42  /dev/tty58      /dev/ttyS14  /dev/ttyS3
/dev/tty12  /dev/tty28  /dev/tty43  /dev/tty59      /dev/ttyS15  /dev/ttyS30
/dev/tty13  /dev/tty29  /dev/tty44  /dev/tty6       /dev/ttyS16  /dev/ttyS31
/dev/tty14  /dev/tty3   /dev/tty45  /dev/tty60      /dev/ttyS17  /dev/ttyS4
/dev/tty15  /dev/tty30  /dev/tty46  /dev/tty61      /dev/ttyS18  /dev/ttyS5
/dev/tty16  /dev/tty31  /dev/tty47  /dev/tty62      /dev/ttyS19  /dev/ttyS6
/dev/tty17  /dev/tty32  /dev/tty48  /dev/tty63      /dev/ttyS2   /dev/ttyS7
/dev/tty18  /dev/tty33  /dev/tty49  /dev/tty7       /dev/ttyS20  /dev/ttyS8
/dev/tty19  /dev/tty34  /dev/tty5   /dev/tty8       /dev/ttyS21  /dev/ttyS9
/dev/tty2   /dev/tty35  /dev/tty50  /dev/tty9       /dev/ttyS22
/dev/tty20  /dev/tty36  /dev/tty51  /dev/ttyprintk  /dev/ttyS23
/dev/tty21  /dev/tty37  /dev/tty52  /dev/ttyS0      /dev/ttyS24
/dev/tty22  /dev/tty38  /dev/tty53  /dev/ttyS1      /dev/ttyS25
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you try /dev/ttyS0 instead?

Comment: Attempting that returns the error `avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding`

Comment: I've had some success adding a udevrule for my Arduino explicitly. Mine (for nano is `SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{idProduct}=="6001", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0403", SYMLINK+="ttyArduino%n"` and creates /dev/ttyArduinoX. There must be a similar rule for Uno?

Comment: Could you run `dmesg -w` and `udevadm monitor -u` in separate terminals then plug that Arduino. Add the new output to the question.